# Color Coding with Multiple Conditions in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, conditional-formatting

I have a piece of code that looks at percentages as the condition of how it gets color coded. I am wondering if I can add a condition based on another column, then apply it to my effected column.

So If Column "Time Spent in Default Aux Time 0" has more than 1 hour of time, then my color coding condition statements apply. But if this column has less than 1 hour of time, the color coding does not apply.

Below is a sample of my code. I only included the piece relevant to this question as I know the entire code works.

```
With .CalculatedFields.Add("DefaultCode_0_Time", "=DefaultCode_0/86400")
    .Orientation = 4
    .Function = -4157
    .NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss"
    .Caption = "Time Spent in Default Aux Time 0"
End With   ####This is the piece I wanted factored in to the condition. 
           If this column is more than ah hour, I want the color coding 
           condition below applied. If it is less than 1 hour, then I do 
            not want the color coding condition below applied####

With .CalculatedFields.Add("Aux_0_Percentage", "=ACD_Aux_Outtime/DefaultCode_0")
    .Orientation = 4
    .NumberFormat = "#,##0.0%"
    .Caption = "Default Aux Time 0 % for Outbound Calls"
End With

  Set xlObj = .PivotFields("Default Aux Time 0 % for Outbound Calls").DataRange.FormatConditions.Add(1, 1, "0.00", "0.4") '(xlCellValue, xlBetween, "0-40%")
    xlObj.StopIfTrue = False
    xlObj.ScopeType = 1
    With xlObj.Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    With xlObj.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = -4105 'xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615 'red
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

Set xlObj = Nothing

Set xlObj = .PivotFields("Default Aux Time 0 % for Outbound Calls").DataRange.FormatConditions.Add(1, 1, "0.40", "0.50") '(xlCellValue, xlBetween, "40-50%")
    xlObj.StopIfTrue = False
    xlObj.ScopeType = 1
    With xlObj.Font
        .Color = -16752384
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    With xlObj.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = -4105 'xlAutomatic
        .Color = 10284031 'yellow
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

Set xlObj = Nothing
```

Comment: The code would be clearer if you replaced the hard-coded `1, 1` values in `FormatConditions.Add` with their respective `xlFormatConditionType` and `xlFormatConditionOperator` named constants (`xlCellValue` and `xlBetween`, respectively); I think I'd set `StopIfTrue = True`, and rename the first `xlObj` to e.g. `smallValuesFormat`, and the second to e.g. `mediumValuesFormat` (avoid reusing variables for different purposes in the same scope). Looks like the condition for <1h needs to also be a conditional format - do you get to access its `.DataRange` in the top `With` block?

Comment: Yes I get its .DataRange in the top With block.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Yes I get its .DataRange in the top 'With block'